# Importing .csv with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, ipython

I'm doing analysis on research awards and have analyzed and visualized one year of data in ipython already. When I try a similar approach with an years before 2013 I get either ERROR, line contains NULL byte or VALUE ERROR no columns to parse, depending on whether I use the python or c engine, respectively. I also checked for a better explanation in the source code and tinkered with arguments from the documentation but I keep getting the same outputs. Nothing I have found so far on forums has explained it too well either.

Is there some way around this using pandas or would another .csv import method be suggested? Is it possible that there is some formatting variation between 2012 and 2013? Each of all files before 2013 are around double the size of 2013 (with 2013 at 38.4MB, 2012 at 74.2MB, and 2011 at 77.2MB), but have roughly the same number of entries. I eventually want to combine all of the years of data together so if this can be resolved using pandas that would be great. Did I miss or misinterpret something?

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_rows', 20)
pd.set_option('max_columns', 20)

#source csv, change year to get different years down to 2008
#'http://www.research.gov/common/attachment/Common/exportAwards-2012.csv'
url = "/home/derp/Downloads/exportAwards-2012.csv"

a12 = pd.read_csv(url) #with different modified arguments
a12
```

I am using Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. Pandas= 0.14.0

Comment: Can you provide a small example of sample data that shows the problem?  It sounds like there is something wrong in your data file, but it's hard to know.

Comment: Figured it out. You helped me follow a hunch. It was an encoding difference.

Comment: Just wondering, how did u do it?

Comment: Manually. I opened them in Excel and saved them as utf-8 encoded .csv. Not the most elegant solution but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the file `http://www.research.gov/common/attachment/Common/exportAwards-2012.csv` For some reason, there are a lot of NULL (\000). If you open it with Vi you can see them (^@).

You can pre-process the file: since you are on Ubuntu

```
tr < exportAwards-2012.csv -d '\000' > exportAwards-2012_2.csv
```

Then `pd.read_csv` should be able to read `exportAwards-2012_2.csv`.

Comment: I'll make sure to do this in the future.